# Proving properties regarding a circle

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I show that for a circle centered at the origin and with a radius 1, there are more boundary points containing an irrational number as one of the coordinate as compared to boundary points containing only rational numbers as both of their coordinates?

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be larger than another one ?

Comment: It contain more elements.

Comment: The set of rationals is countable; the set of irrationals is uncountable.

Comment: I am aware of that but how can I incorporate that statement over here?

Comment: @FaiqRaees you can't do any math with "it contains more elements".

Comment: @GabrielRomon I am aware of that. However I am not really good at proofs regarding sets.

Comment: @FaiqRaees My understanding is that you want to know which set has great cardinality (hence my answer, below).  Assuming that this is correct, can you please edit your question to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

The set
$$ \mathbb{Q}^2 = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x,y\in\mathbb{Q} \right\}, $$
i.e. the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with rational coefficients is countable, and so any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has at most countably infinite points with rational coefficients.  In fact, it turns out that this set is infinite, though the argument is a bit technical.  Perhaps an easy way to see this is to note that there are an infinite number of Pythagorean triples, each of which (by scaling) corresponds to a point on the unit circle.  In any event, the cardinality of points on the unit circle with rational coefficients is, indeed, countably infinite.

On the other hand, the collection of points in the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin, i.e. the set
$$ S^1 := \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \right\}, $$
is uncountable (to see this, note that we can construct a bijection from the circle to the interval $[0,2\pi)$---if you want to be explicit about it, define
$$ f : [0,2\pi) \to S^1 \qquad\text{by}\qquad (\cos(t),\sin(t)); $$
it can be verified without too much difficulty that $f$ is bijective).  Therefore
$$ |S^1| > |S^1 \cap \mathbb{Q}^2| $$
that is, the cardinality of points in the circle is greater than the cardinality of rational points in the circle.

---

Addendum:  there are at most two points on the unit circle that have any given $x$-coordinate.  Thus for any rational number $q\in[-1,1]$, there are at most two points in the unit circle of the form $(q,y)$.  There are countably infinitely many such points, hence the cardinality of points in the unit circle with a rational $x$-coordinate is countably infinite.  That is,
$$ S^1 \cap \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : x\in\mathbb{Q} \right\} $$
is countably infinite.  similarly,
$$ S^1 \cap \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : y\in\mathbb{Q} \right\} $$
is countably infinite.  The union of countable sets is countable, and the union of the above two sets (by De Morgan) is given by
$$ S^1 \cap \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : x\in\mathbb{Q} \lor y\in\mathbb{Q} \right\}. $$
But this set is exactly the set of points in the unit circle that have at least one rational coordinate.  Therefore the set of points in the unit circle with at least one rational coordinate is countable.  Thus the cardinality of points in the unit circle with at least one rational coordinate is equal to the cardinality of points in the unit circle with two rational coordinates, but less than the cardinality of the unit circle.

---

Finally, let us consider the set of points on the unit circle with *exactly* one rational coordinate and one irrational coordinate.  By the arguments above, this is at most a countably infinite set (as it is contained in the union discussed above), hence we would like to know if it is finite or not.  We can see that this set is infinite by, for example, finding an infinite subset.  So consider the set of right triangles with a let of unit length and a hypotenuse of integer length such that the hypotenuse is not one more than a perfect square.  The remaining leg will be of irrational length.  By scaling, this triangle will correspond to a point on the unit circle with exactly one rational coordinate.  There are infinitely many such triangles, so there are countably infinitely many points on the unit circle with exactly one rational and exactly one irrational coordinate.

---

In summary:

1. The unit circle is uncountable.
2. The set of points on the unit circle with at least one rational coordinate is countably infinite.
3. The set of points on the unit circle with exactly one rational coordinate is countably infinite.
4. The set of points on the unit circle with two rational coordinates is countably infinite.

Hence the latter three sets are "the same size," i.e. they have the same cardinalities.

Comment: In both of the set notations, the starting statement was the same yet the first one is countable and second isnt. Can you please explain that?

Comment: Do you know how to read the notation?  $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x,y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is read "the set of elements $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are rational."  The stuff before the colon tells you where the points live, and the stuff after the colon places additional restrictions on them.

Comment: Okay I get the first part. Since rational are countable hence the first set notation(which is basically another way to write Q) is also countable. But I cant get the second one. (It would be very helpful if you dont use the symbols and the word bijective)

Comment: It is not another way of writing $\mathbb{Q}$.  It is a way of describing the points in two-dimensional space that have only rational coefficients, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: Yes yes sorry for the confusion. Can you please answer the second statement of my previous post?

Comment: @Faiq Raees I believe what is meant here is that there is a one-to-one matching between the points on the unit circle on one hand, and the real numbers from 0 to 2 pi on the other hand. That's because the unit circle has circumference 2 pi.

Comment: As I wrote above, $S^1$ is the circle.  It is the collection of points $(x,y)$ in two dimensional space that satisfy the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  A "bijection" is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of two sets.  But if you are having problems with the notation and vocabulary, I might suggest that you need to sit down and study up on elementary set theory a bit more before you try to tackle this problem.

Comment: Hello I think you missed one point. My question was to prove there are more boundary points containing an IRRATIONAL NUMBER as ONE of the coordinate as compared to boundary points containing only rational numbers as both of their coordinates. I dont think you accounted for that. If I am wrong please do not mind me and please tell where you accounted for them.

Comment: @FaiqRaees The set of points with at least one irrational coordinate is the complement of the set of points with two rational coordinates.  The latter set is countable, while the unit circle is uncountable, thus the set of points with at least one irrational coordinate is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

The maps \begin{align}\sigma:&S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}\to \Bbb R\\ &(x,y)\mapsto \frac{x}{1-y}\\ \tau:&\Bbb R\to S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}\\ &t\mapsto \left(\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}\right)\end{align}

satisfy $\sigma\circ\tau=id_{\Bbb R}$ and $\tau\circ\sigma=id_{S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}}$. Moreover, $\sigma$ maps bijectively $S^1\cap\Bbb Q^2\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ to $\Bbb Q$ (with inverse $\left.\tau\right\rvert_{\Bbb Q}$) and the remaining points to the irrationals. The rest is your favourite argument for the irrationals being the same cardinality of $\Bbb R$.